# Unable to upload Solang generated idl

Tags: anchor, idl, anchor-program-idl

```
$ anchor idl init -f target/idl/program.json `solana address -k target/deploy/program-keypair.json` 

Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument [3 log messages]

Caused by:
    RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid program argument [3 log messages]
```

I have been unable to find:

- the error `-32002` specific to this case
- the log messages mentioned in the brackets
- what does Instruction 0 mean
- which program argument is invalid
- any solution in general

Solang version: v0.3.2
Anchor-cli version: v0.28.0
Solana-cli version: v1.16.17

edit to add my instruction 0:

```
    {
      "name": "new",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": true,
          "isOptional": false
        },
        {
          "name": "payer",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": true,
          "isOptional": false
        },
        {
          "name": "systemProgram",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    }
```

edit: I experimented with changing the function order and its arguments and the problem is still there, suggesting to me a compatibility issue.

edit:
You can reproduce this by trying to deploy the program created with:

```
anchor init program --solidity
```

[Opened issue in anchor github](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround, since `idl` files are simple `.json` files you can bundle it within the web-app and load it with a simple:

```
import idl from "./testprogram.json";
...
new anchor.Program(idl, ...)
```

Edit:
Even better, you may copy the `target/types/testprogram.ts` file into the app and import both the IDL and Contract type with:

```
import { Testprogram, IDL } from "./testprogram";
```